# XML File Error Validation

Tags: xml, validation, dtd

As I placed a Product Xml Dtd File to be checked and validated at: https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi I have gotten this answer:

"Sorry

This feed does not validate.
line 3, column 0: Undefined root element: catalog"

I place here a part of the Product Catalog XML DTD code, so may someone can help me out where is the error and how to fix it. Another Validator  site says it has a blank at line "1" and column "1" and for that it can not be validated. Please, what I must do?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE product_catalog SYSTEM "http://www.sitename.com/content/dtd/product_catalog_1_1.dtd">
<catalog>
<product>
<programname>SiteName.com</programname>
<programurl>http://www.sitename.com?aff=lmcom</programurl>
<catalogname>Productfeed Master EN / USD</catalogname>
<lastupdated>2017-03-20 09:01:30.22</lastupdated>
<name>Dolce &amp; Gabbana blouse</name>
<keywords>Dolce &amp; Gabbana, Cotton, Elastane, dark blue</keywords>
<description>Timeless Dolce &amp; Gabbana shirt.</description>
<sku>F-01-Bl-40751</sku>
<manufacturer>Dolce &amp; Gabbana</manufacturer>
<upc>4251259825500</upc>
<currency>USD</currency>
<price>69</price>
<retailprice>249</retailprice>
<buyurl>http://www.sitename.com/click-9XXXXX6-YYYYYYYY?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sitename.com%2Fus%2Ftimeless-dolce-and-gabbana-shirt-5.html</buyurl>
<impressionurl>http://www.ftjcfx.com/image-9XXXXX6-YYYYYYYY</impressionurl>
<imageurl>http://images.sitename.uk/productimages/export_big/40700_1.jpg</imageurl>
<advertisercategory>Women &gt; blouse</advertisercategory>
<instock>yes</instock>
<standardshippingcost>16.57</standardshippingcost>
</product>
<product>
<programname>SiteName.com</programname>
<programurl>http://www.sitename.com?aff=lmcom</programurl>
<catalogname>Productfeed Master EN / USD</catalogname>
<lastupdated>2017-03-20 09:01:30.438</lastupdated>
<name>Carrera sunglasses</name>
<keywords>Carrera, Metal, purple</keywords>
<description>Carrera. 100% Metal.</description>
<sku>U-83-So-43547</sku>
<manufacturer>Carrera</manufacturer>
<upc>4251259925500</upc>
<currency>USD</currency>
<price>59</price>
<retailprice>129</retailprice>
<buyurl>http://www.sitename.net/click-9XXXXX6-YYYYYYYY?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sitename.com%2Fus%2Fcarrera-11.html</buyurl>
<impressionurl>http://www.ftjcfx.com/image-9XXXXX6-YYYYYYYY</impressionurl>
<imageurl>http://images.sitename.uk/productimages/export_big/43701_1.jpg</imageurl>
<advertisercategory>Unisex &gt; sunglasses</advertisercategory>
<instock>yes</instock>
<standardshippingcost>16.57</standardshippingcost>
</product>
</catalog>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE product_catalog SYSTEM "http://www.sitename.com/content/dtd/product_catalog_1_1.dtd">
<catalog>
```

The name appearing after DOCTYPE must match the outermost element name, for example

```
<!DOCTYPE catalog SYSTEM "http://www.sitename.com/content/dtd/product_catalog_1_1.dtd">
    <catalog>
```

Comment: Hello Michael Kay, After following your advice the site came with this note: `This feed does not validate.
line 3, column 0: Undefined root element: catalog <catalog>` Some say that validation could not be done after a file has been uploaded and tried to validated too many times, which is its case. It was validated before by the site validator: http://www.validome.org/xml/; that can’t be reached;  `DNS address could not be found.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`  Thank You! Warm Regards! Cheers! LFaber

Comment: Perhaps you need to change it to `product_catalog` then. I have no idea which is correct, all I was saying was that it has to be the same in the instance and the DTD.

Comment: Or catalog_product? Here english grammar meets the code grammar! Thank you! LFaber.